# Convolution of non negative, symmetric, decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, convolution

Suppose $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ are non negative, even and decreasing on $[0,\infty)$. Prove that their convolution $f * g$ is even and decreasing on $[0,\infty)$.

**Attempt:** It is easy to show that $f * g$ is even, this simply follows from a change of variables. But how to show that it is decreasing? Let $0\leq x<z$. Then:

$f*g(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)g(x-y)dy$

$f*g(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)g(z-y)dy$

I need somehow to show that the first integral is at least as large as the second one. I tried to split the domain into parts. Since $f$ is non negative multiplication by it preserves inequalities. So if $y<x$ then $f(y)g(x-y)\geq f(y)g(z-y)$. If $y>z$ then $f(y)g(x-y)\leq f(y)g(z-y)$ (since on the negative real line the function $g$ is increasing, follows from it being even). So taking these inequalities inside the integrals gives us:

$\int_{y<x}f(y)g(x-y)\geq\int_{y<x}f(y)g(z-y)dy$

And there is a reverse inequality on $\{y>z\}$. So intuitively the interval $(-\infty, x)$ is "longer" than $(z,\infty)$ and contains more values near the origin, which is where $f$ and $g$ are large. However, I don't see how can it be written formally. Also, there remains the interval $\{x\leq y\leq z\}$ where there are no such inequalities, so it's difficult to say what does it add to both integrals. Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: first show that the result is true when $f=\chi_{[-n,n]},\ g=\chi_{[-m,m]}$, which is easy since in this case $\int f(y)g(x-y)dy=\lambda([-n,n]\cap [-m+x,m+x])$ then use the linearity of the integral in $f$ and $g$ together with an approximation argument for the general case.

Comment: Yes, I also had an idea to start from such functions, but I got stuck. But I think I got it now, because $f$ and $g$ can be approximated by a sequence of step functions, and then by dominated convergence we can take the limit inside the integrals. (and since they are even we can choose these step functions to be even and decreasing)